# How can I look for a smart radio player that automatically restart when the buffer gets empty?

Tags: software-recommendation, streaming, multimedia, cache

I am tired to have the streaming broken. I tried **rhythmbox**, **totem**, **audacious**, even **vlc** where I configured 5 seconds of cache.

The sound stops for a while then continue, most of times from the same moment it has stopped, I believe the streaming speed fluctuates, may be my internet, may be the server, the fact is, if my player was a little bit smarter, I wouldn't have such a bad experience.

I wonder if it wouldn't be so hard to a developer to check if the streaming buffer is close to being empty, then start a second streaming thread, such as double buffering, if the former thread recovers its cache, the second thread should be cancelled. Otherwise the former thread should be closed and the new one takes its place.

Does this technique have a name? How can I look for a player with this feature?

Comment: why does it get broken? I mean the streaming... Are you facing connectivity issues? Because I can listen for hours to radio using Guayadeque media player with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: The sound stops for a while then continue, most of times from the same moment it has stopped, I believe the streaming speed fluctuates, may be my internet, may be the server, the fact is, if my player was a little bit smarter, I wouldn't have such a bad experience.

Comment: it mostly sounds like the issues with your internet connection speed maybe you should address to your provider. I dunno if there's such media utility or a quick fix to it available, unless someone will be empowered to write a script for it, etc.

Comment: You may be right, it may be the provider, but may be the network itself, you know, wireless has their problems, but even at work, and in my mom's house, where it's wired, it happens, I would be glad if some holy soul provide the solution for this issue, I'm sure I'm not the only one who suffer with that.

Comment: It might seen a workaround, but it certainly is a worthwhile contribution for those people who gets annoyed by the streaming flux variance.

Comment: What version of Rhythmbox are you using? Buffering has greatly improved since version 3 and even in unstable networks its behaviour is congruent (it either works or it doesn't). If indeed an unstable connection is the source of your troubles, double buffering will not solve it.

Comment: I am using trusty, rhythmbox 3.0.2